# Fastest way to compute an expression func result given parameters

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection, lambda, expression

I receive an `Expression<Func<...,...,...,TResult>>` (random, but fixed number of parameters) instance in a form of a general `Expression` type.

For instance:

```
Expression<Func<int,int,int>> adderExpression = (a,b) => a+b;
LambdaExpression receivedExpression = adderExpression;
//Later on, I get only the receivedExpression variable and an array of values for which I have to compute:
var values = new object[] {3, 4};
var result = receivedExpression.Compile().DynamicInvoke(values);
```

The only thing I have access to is the `receivedExpression` variable and an array of object values for which I have to compute the result of applying the compiled expression.

The `receivedExpression` does not change: once I get it, it remains the same.

What is the fastest way I can compute the `result` variable given my circumstances? `DynamicInvoke` is super slow in this case, and I was wondering if there is a faster way to compute the result.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile since there is no method `Compile` on `Expression`.

Comment: Perhaps it should be `LambdaExpression receivedExpression`?

Comment: Do you know any of the types involved, especially the return type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a compiled delegate that takes the argument array and uses `Invoke` to call the passed in `Expression`, effectively creating dynamically the equivalent of:

```
var rec = receivedExpression.Compile();
var f = (object[] p) => (object)rec.Invoke((type0)p[0],(type1)p[1],...);
```

First, you will need to convert the (unknown) return type of the `receivedExpression` to `object` so you can create a strongly typed delegate:

```
var fr = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Convert(receivedExpression.Body, typeof(object)), receivedExpression.Parameters);
```

Then you can create the `Expression` for a lambda that takes an `object[]` and calls a lambda with a fixed number and type of arguments.

First you will need a parameter for the lambda:

```
var arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object[]));
```

Then you will need to convert each member of that `object[]` parameter to the correct type to pass to `receivedExpression`:

```
var args = values.Select((v, i) => Expression.Convert(Expression.ArrayIndex(arg, Expression.Constant(i)), v.GetType())).ToArray();
```

Then you can create the new lambda:

```
var frs = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Invoke(fr, args), arg);
```

Then you compile that lambda containing the passed in `Expression`:

```
var frsc = (Func<object[], object>)frs.Compile();
```

Finally, you can use the new lambda to call the `receivedExpression` efficiently:

```
object result = frsc.Invoke(values);
```

Comment: Nice one! I wonder if there is an even faster way than Invoke to do this. Still, your approach goes from ~709ns (using DynamicInvoke) to 56ns (using your method).

Comment: `Invoke` is how the compiler translates regular function calls into `Expression` trees, so I think it is as efficient as possible. Checking a literal call to a `Func<>` shows it using `Invoke` in the IL.